# Join only certain values a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can make a string from certain values from a list of dictionaries ?
I would like to only join the values of 'first_name' and 'last_name' from the dictionaries.

```
[{"id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"},
 {"id": 1, "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Carry"},
 ...]
```

Comment: Can you post both your attempt at solving this, as well as an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
L = [{"id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"},
     {"id": 1, "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Carry"}]

for i in L:
    i['full_name'] = '{0} {1}'.format(i['first_name'], i['last_name'])

print(L)

[{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'full_name': 'John Smith'},
 {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Tom', 'last_name': 'Carry', 'full_name': 'Tom Carry'}]
```

Then, to extract a list of full names, you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [i['full_name'] for i in L]

print(res)

['John Smith', 'Tom Carry']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way would be:

```
lst = [{"id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"},
 {"id": 1, "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Carry"}]

for x, y in [(d['first_name'], d['last_name']) for d in lst]:
    print(f'{x} {y}')

# John Smith
# Tom Carry
```